# How do I use node-ipc and express at the same time

Tags: node.js, express, node-ipc

I want to use both node-ipc and express in the same script but each use blocking methods to start their respective servers.  I saw the threads package but wanted to verify.  What is best practice to run both servers at the same time?

Thanks!

Comment: They do not use blocking methods.

Comment: Care to clarify how to use both at the same time? When you run ipc.serve() or express.listen() no code following either call will be executed.

Comment: That should not be true.

Comment: Entirely correct.  I just re-ran the code on cloud9 and the http server is working now.  My error entirely.  Thanks.